# What is a easiest way to implement Mail Server in ubuntu and hook in webmail through XAMPP?

Tags: ubuntu, email, xampp, easy-install

I currently have xampp running on my ubuntu server. I tried a variety of things including installing, postfix+dovecot+roundcube+postfixadmin (postfix+dovecot work I think, postfix admin also works, roundcube works and connects to dovecot but i cant create user accounts, or figure out how that works), citadel (it installed, but I have no idea how to make it work with xampp for webmail) and i tried messing with exim and vexim a bit also. In short I feel like this should be a lot easier, and I can't figure it out haha.

XAMPP works fine. I got my server running with everything. I was thinking about mercury mail, but I need a webmail solution also. I was thinking about google apps, but 50 bucks a year per user is a steep change from free.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't even know there was a XAMPP release for Linux. You see, an ubuntu LAMP server nowadays can get installed out of the box without touching a .conf file.

For the mail server stack, by far the best resource i am aware of on the internet is
http://johnny.chadda.se/2007/04/15/mail-server-howto-postfix-and-dovecot-with-mysql-and-tlsssl-postgrey-and-dspam/

I have followed the aforementioned howto and then installed horde3 for webmail 3 times already in two different data-centers

Answer (score 0):

Old topic, but lately, I realized (at least for sending mail) using sendmail is a pretty good solution. I also use gmail for actually email accounts. This seems to work nicely.